# Volumes for Linux containers on windows host

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm new to docker. I want to run the ngnix server inside a windows container but the ngnix image is available only for Linux. So, I have switched to Linux containers on windows and created the container using that image and configured the port 80 of the container to my host port 8000.

it's working and I saw the ngnix index page. The problem is I want to move my static site to this container but when I created and mounted the volume to the container, the volume is created inside the `mobilinux`.

So, I want to push my static files sites to that volume where as in case of windows container the volume is create in the host machine file system I can inspect the volume using `docker volume inspect <volumename>` command and figure out the folder and I can able to place my code there. I need help to push my code in to the Linux container from windows host.

I can use bash inside the container and able to edit the html files after installing vim editor inside the container. But when I tried to connect to the mobilinux vm from hyper-v manager, I can't connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to share your local drives (volumes) with Docker Desktop for Windows, so that they are available to your Linux containers.

Something like follows:

[image]

Then something like next will work:

```
docker run -idt -v C:/your_folder_on_windows:/your_folder_in_container nginx
```

You can just put code in `C:/your_folder_on_windows`, and will be ready in `/your_folder_in_container` of your container.

Details refer to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives)

Comment: This no longer applies if you're using WSL2.  This is described in the provided official guide link.